# Binary is not a valid representation for an ObjectIdSerializer

Tags: mongodb, bson, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to set the ObjectId from my TestObject class. The only problem is I keep getting exceptions and I have no way of debugging this serialization process.

My MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : LUUID("964c87a0-bf8a-1f4e-be85-7aadb5315adb")
}
```

> An error has occurred while resolving 'MongoDataSource' data source: An error occurred while invaking data retrieval method.
>
> --- InnerException ---
>
> An error occurred while deserializing the Object property of class TestObject: Cannot deserialize a 'ObjectId' from BsonType 'Binary'.
>
> --- InnerException ---
>
> Cannot deserialize a 'ObjectId' from BsonType 'Binary'.

```
[DataObject]
public class TestObject
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    public ObjectId ObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

If I make it a BsonType.Binary

> An error has occurred while resolving 'MongoDataSource' data source: An error occurred while invaking data retrieval method.
>
> --- InnerException ---
>
> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> --- InnerException ---
>
> Binary is not a valid representation for an ObjectIdSerializer.

```
[DataObject]
public class TestObject
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Binary)]
    public ObjectId ObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it should not be cast to an `ObjectId` type then. In other words you are making a change in the annotation and serializer but you forgot to change the "type" of the property in the class itself. Sort of like stuffing a square peg into a round hole, as the saying goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the field inside Mongo collection is stored as `LUUID` (it's a GUID) that is a completely different type compared to an ObjectId.

In your mapping class, you defined

```
[DataObject]
public class TestObject
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    public ObjectId ObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

and when the driver tries to deserialize the value `964c87a0-bf8a-1f4e-be85-7aadb5315adb` (string representation of a GUID) fails.

Good news an id generator for GUID ships with the drivers and you can easily achieve the desired result just by following the driver's conventions:

```
public class TestObject
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } // note the property is renamed in Id
}
```

As per [official documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/bson/mapping/#the-id-member) you can omit `[BsonId]` `[BsonElement("_id")]` and `[BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(GuidGenerator))]` attributes as long as the property is named `Id` and its type is one of the supported ones.